# Trying to bind 2 different webdatagrids with button.click

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have 2 different web data grids i would like to populate when i click a button. It works fine whenever i just had one datagrid, but i cant get the 2nd datagrid to populate. Thank you in advance for your responses.
This is my code, i replaced the select statements to save yall some reading:

```
 Protected Sub ViewButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
                                                   Handles ViewButton.Click

    Dim GroupName As String = GroupDropDown.SelectedValue

    Dim MySqlString As String = "SELECT STATEMENT"

    Dim MyDataTable As DataTable = OleFun.GetMyDataTableString(MySqlString, 2)

    WebDataGrid1.DataSource = MyDataTable
    WebDataGrid1.DataBind()

    Dim MySqlString2 As String = "SELECT STATEMENT"
    Dim MyDataTable2 As DataTable = OleFun.GetMyDataTableString(MySqlString2, 2)

    WebDataGrid2.DataSource = MyDataTable2
    WebDataGrid2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do both populate on their own?

Comment: On button click the 1st Datagrid still populates, but for some reason the second one wont

Comment: Have to tried running the second one on its own?

Comment: I just did, it's not wokring on. I guess i should figure that out first haha

Comment: Does the second SQL statement return anything?